# OL3 check constrain point drag to lineString?

Tags: openlayers, drag-and-drop

I am wanting to allow the user to be able to drag a map marker, in OpenLayers 3, but constrain the dragging to the lineString that represents the route. Based on the code example on [Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605100/how-to-drag-features-in-open-layers-3) I am able to move the marker and have an onChange handler, as follows:

```
geoMarker.on('change',function() {
    var point = scope.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    if ( scope.map.getLayer('routeLayer').getSource().getFeaturesAtCoordinate(point) == 0 ) {
        // TODO if point is not in lineString, then prevent drag
    } else {
        // TODO get index of nearest point in routeLine and display
        //      location information
    }
});
```

I looked at the OpenLayers 3 examples, but nothing jumped out as how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example taken from here : http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/examples/igc.html

```
  var displaySnap = function(coordinate) {
    var closestFeature = vectorSource.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(coordinate);
    var info = document.getElementById('info');
    if (closestFeature === null) {
      point = null;
      line = null;
      info.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    } else {
      var geometry = closestFeature.getGeometry();
      var closestPoint = geometry.getClosestPoint(coordinate);
      if (point === null) {
        point = new ol.geom.Point(closestPoint);
      } else {
        point.setCoordinates(closestPoint);
      }
      var date = new Date(closestPoint[2] * 1000);
      info.innerHTML =
          closestFeature.get('PLT') + ' (' + date.toUTCString() + ')';
      var coordinates = [coordinate, [closestPoint[0], closestPoint[1]]];
      if (line === null) {
        line = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates);
      } else {
        line.setCoordinates(coordinates);
      }
    }
    map.render();
  };

  map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    if (evt.dragging) {
      return;
    }
    var coordinate = map.getEventCoordinate(evt.originalEvent);
    displaySnap(coordinate);
  });

  map.on('click', function(evt) {
    displaySnap(evt.coordinate);
  });
```